# CNN: Why stack same activation maps on top of each other

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, convolution

I am wondering why we stack basically identical activation maps on top of each other? Since it's always the same filter applied on the same input, wouldn't it be always the same activation map?

If that's the case, we wouldn't even need to recompute the activation map, but just copy the activation map N times. What additional information does this provide us? Yes, we create again a layer with depth (output volume), but if it's the same value, what is the rational behind it?

[image]
Src: http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2017/cs231n_2017_lecture5.pdf

Comment: I don't really fully understand your question, but each filter map uses different weights. So each activation map is going to have different values.

Comment: The activation maps as you call them are not identical, because its not the same filter applied to the input.

Comment: Thanks both of you. Makes absolutely sense. Not sure how I could oversea this obvious fact. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the same convolution, you have separate, independent kernel (filters) for each activation map (independent weights), thus they are completely different. Without it, after convolution we would only have one "type of feature" extracted, say edges; while for CNNs to work we need plenty of these.

In the example provided the "green 5x5x3 filter" produces one, green activation map, then you have separate "blue 5x5x3 filter" that produces blue activation map and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Actually we don't stack same activation maps on top of each other.It is only the shape of each activation map that retains the same(in your case, it is 5*5*3).But the weights among different activation maps are absolutely different.
1. each activation map share the same weights. that is a single activation map is used to detect a specific kind of feature appears in different locations of the original map.
2. different activation maps are used to detect different kinds of features.